# Microsoft Graph API: @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl behavior for personal accounts

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

When using a business account, a DriveItem's [@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem) is like

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/personal/company_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=qSklOMSL1z7jxyzfOP2GzK7tRltRKID4MwS410%4xyzEw%3d&docid=99fgd92d528624b41b1329bfa1a25d0b3&expiration=2016-11-16T02%3a59%3a57.000Z&userid=3&authurl=True&NeverAuth=True
```

If I put this URL in a browser, I get the file (with the right name and extension. e.g. **myimage.png**). Everything is OK.

When using a personal account, a DriveItem's @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property is like

```
https://public-bn1306.files.1drv.com/z1mKhEKmWDB2Yp1BCG21GcBwx5vPRHkP7adGcIE3GIdipHvNJdGIhjq8leiZVSwSfCH1L--otP_KHx5FopV8TUs8GJJm0X8Ag1Rh504tnJP1mxuGoM-LNCFkGGZl01qZzsTr99xBTDDgwIKaZs21UYV4L_-d8EmSktRG1i-r57ERhRuknnJRGeX_MOlBT3VPzd
```

If I put this URL in a browser, I get a file with name **z1mKhEKmWDB2Yp1BCG21GcBwx5vPRHkP7adGcIE3GIdipHvNJdGIhjq8leiZVSwSfCH1L--otP_KHx5FopV8TUs8GJJm0X8Ag1Rh504tnJP1mxuGoM-LNCFkGGZl01qZzsTr99xBTDDgwIKaZs21UYV4L_-d8EmSktRG1i-r57ERhRuknnJRGeX_MOlBT3VPzd** and no extension.

This is not OK. 
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser takes the last segment of the URL to be the suggested name when downloading (if there's no disposition header), and so to work around you can grab the value of the `name` item and append it as a new segment to the URL's path. So in your example:

`https://public-bn1306.files.1drv.com/z1*snip*zd/filename.txt`

Edit: I should add that this is obviously not ideal, and we'll definitely look into making the behavior for the consumer service match that of the business service.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I'll wait for the fix. Meanwhile I'll keep using the Live SDK for consumer accounts.

Comment: Hi there. Is there any ETA for a fix (i.e. consistent behavior regardless of being a business or personal account)?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I believe this should be resolved now

Comment: Same here (apologies for the delay) :). yes, It is resolved. Thanks!